# Using VS Code, how can I add a durable function to a function app with target framework 5.0

Tags: azure-functions

I have an existing function app that I have been experimenting with using VS Code and .NET 5. I have the latest Azure Functions extension installed. When I do `Azure Functions: create function`, I do not get see the Durable Orchestration Function. However, if I create another function app using .NET 3.1 and do `create function`, I see the Durable template. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe durable functions are not supported in .Net5 yet. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions), [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/net-5-support-on-azure-functions/ba-p/1973055) and [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/03/24/azure-functions-net5.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

azure durable functions for '.net 5' is not supported now.

Check this announcement:

[While the .NET isolated model supports most Azure Functions triggers and bindings, Durable Functions and rich types support are currently unavailable.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916)

The announcement stated that there is no plan to provide support in this area for the time being, and it may only begin to be gradually realized in 2022. So if you want to use durable function, you still need to be based on something like .Net Core 3.1.